# Ask user to enter an integer value for each element of the array

Tags: c, arrays, integer

• Declare an array type of int and size of 5
• Ask user to enter an integer value for each element of the array
• Then display every element of the array user entered

please help me where to start i don't know much about array.

Comment: start by learning about [array](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_arrays.htm)

Comment: Declare an array type of int  and size of 5 --> `int a[5];` to get your started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One advice, if you don't learn for yourself, then nobody can teach you. So, please try researching a bit on the internet, or reading a good book before you post a question.

Assuming this is your first mistake, and you wont repeat this without working a little on your own, i'll provide the code and the explanation..

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int arr[5], i;

    printf("please enter the numbers one by one");
    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
         scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
    }

    printf("The numbers you entered are\n");
    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
         printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    }
}
```